# SpringBoot: can't create fully executable jar with 2.0.0-M3

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, executable-jar

I have a multi module Gradle project and I tried to upgrade to 2.0.0-M3.
Following the instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install), I added this to my build script:

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

But when I build I get the following error:

```
Could not set unknown property 'executable' for object of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension.
```

Is it something broken in the milestone or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you build?

Comment: As far as I see `executable` is removed from `2.0.0-M3` and both jar and war are executable by default.

Comment: The jar file is not executable, and even if I change the permission I get an error when I try to execute it. I'm not sure how this thing should work at all, the documentation is a bit fuzzy.

Max, what do you mean? I run `./gradlew build`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The configuration for this has changed in Spring Boot 2.0. Rather than configuring it on the `springBoot` extension, it's now [configured on an individual `BootJar` or `BootWar` task](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-launch-script). For example:

```
bootJar {
    launchScript {
        included = true
    }
}
```

As of Spring Boot 2.0 M4, this configuration has been further simplified:

```
bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
```

You may want to open an issue to correct the documentation that you linked to as it's out of date.

Comment: SpringBoot 2.0.3 working with the `launchScript()` version